# Replace all xarray dataset values with a constant

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset. I want to make a copy of that so it has the same dimensions/coordinates/shape as the original. That's easy.

```py
import xarray as xr

n_segs = 4
n_dates = 5
num_vars = 4
dims = (n_segs, n_dates)

das = [xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(*dims), dims=['seg_id', 'date'])
       for i in range(num_vars)]

ds_orig = xr.Dataset({'a': das[0], 'b': das[1], 'c': das[2], 'd': das[3]})
ds_copy = ds_orig.copy(deep=True)
```

Then I want to assign all the values in the copy a constant value (let's say 1). I've figured out how to do this with `where`:

```py
ds_copy.where(ds_copy == np.nan, other=1)
```

but this assumes that none of my values will be `nan` and is a little counter-intuitive IMO. Is there a more robust way?

I suppose I can also loop through the data variables (which is what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636765/how-to-set-all-the-values-of-an-existing-pandas-dataframe-to-zero) suggests for Pandas)...:

```py
for v in ds_copy.data_vars:
    ds_copy[v].loc[:, :] = 1
```

Maybe what I'm looking for here is a `replace` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the loop approach because it will preserve dtypes from the original values. Only one ellipsis in the `loc` is enough, and the `.data_vars` can be omitted (datasets have a [dictionary interface](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/api.html#dictionary-interface)):

```
for v in ds_copy:
    ds_copy[v].loc[:] = 1
```

To get a more robust version of the `where` version, you can pass `False` directly to make sure `other` will always be used:

```
ds_copy.where(False, 1)
```

When storing ints and floats, keeping or not the dtype will probably not have any effect, however, if there are also string or boolean variables, results may change drastically.

Comment: Thanks, @OriolAbril - very helpful tips